# How to add HTML text in ajax editor control using code

Tags: asp.net, ajax, c#-4.0

I'm using asp.net AJAX controls. I have added an editor for sending an email newsletter.

For that I want to add a default HTML newsletter in a box when I open a page. Then there will be a pre-installed newsletter in the AJAX Editor.

How can I add an HTML newsletter using code in c#?

Answer (score 0):

You can create HTML dynamically using `HtmlControl`, every HTML tag like anchor, select, input has its implementation inheriting from this class.

Full reference: [System.Web.UI.HtmlControls Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.aspx)

Add `System.Web.UI.HtmlControls` reference in your code behind and use it!